# Malihu custom scroll bar (mCustomScrollbar) is creating multiple instances of itself in the same div

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm having an issue where a particular div is opened and it should have the mCustomScrollbar in it.  The div is a job info screen and if I open one then it works fine but if I click on the info button of another job the info dive now has 2 mCustomScrollbars in it and adds up the more times I click.

I've tried sending a destroy command before a creation command to remove any instances already there but then it just doesn't appear at all.  I have tried using it without any commands, which makes multiple instances, as well as with the update command like it seems to be used in the rest of the code but that just keeps it from showing up at all.

I just want there to be only one bar in the div.

Edit: Code -

```
$( '#dialog' ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
var recent_info_user;
$('.job .info').live({


click:function (){



    if($('#jobs-users').attr('class')=='inform' && recent_info_user==$(this).parent().find('.inner').attr('data-id'))
    {
        $('#jobs-users').removeClass();
        $('#view-title-bar').removeClass().addClass('jobs-users');
        $('#jobs-users .users').mCustomScrollbar('update');
        $('#jobs-users .jobs').mCustomScrollbar('update');
                    //$('#jobs-users.inform .user-info').mCustomScrollbar();

    }
    else
    {


    $('#jobs-users').removeClass().addClass('inform');
    $('#view-title-bar').removeClass().addClass('inform');
    $.post('php/set-jobs.php', {
            type: 'getdata',
            jobid: $(this).parent().find('.inner').attr('data-id')
        }, function(response) {

    //Alex 2
    //$('#jobs-users .inform .user-info').mCustomScrollbar('disable');
    //$('#jobs-users.inform .user-info').mCustomScrollbar();
    //$('#jobs-users.inform .user-info').css('overflow', 'auto').mCustomScrollbar("update");
    //Alex 2 End

    $('#jobs-users.inform .user-info .retoucher-email').html(response.retoucher.email);

    $('#jobs-users.inform .user-info .job-notes').html(response.other_notes);


        }, 'json');
        $('#jobs-users .users').mCustomScrollbar('update');
        $('#jobs-users .jobs').mCustomScrollbar('update');
        //$('#jobs-users.inform').mCustomScrollbar('update');
    }
}
});
```

The commented out bits are the things I have tried to add.  There have been other variations on the command I have sent to the scroll bar.

Comment: It sounds like the call to mCustomScrollber() is in the wrong place and is somehow tied to the onClick listener of the info button? Without seeing the code it is difficult to be more precise.

Is the problem that you have one job instance when in fact you need one for each job?

Comment: It is inside the click listener but that seems to be the only place I can get it to actually work from.  I'll add the relevant code to he post.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by creating an if loop that checks for the mCustomScrollbar class and then adds it if it isn't there and updates it if it is.  It's not the most elegant solution but I couldn't get it to work in that div any other way.

Comment: Some code on your solution would be useful for others.